# Route /admin trying to load main page on server

Tags: laravel

So I just pulled my code to this linux server and after some testing realized the /admin route was somehow trying to load the main page, which is weird since on my test server (Windows) it's working well.

The structure of /public looks like this:,

```
/public
    /site
    /admin
```

With the assets for each part of the website inside it's folder.

Console shows a lot of errors related to JS and CSS paths like this:
`http://myip/admin/site/js/popper.min.js` which is curious because the proper path would be `http://myip/admin/js/popper.min.js`.

I tried to change the /admin route to change the route behavior to redirect but it looks like nothing has changed, the route seems to take no action.

Here's my routes file:

```
// Site
Route::get('/', 'SliderController@showSlider'); // Show Sliders
Route::redirect('/admin', '/login');

// Autenticação
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // Admin
    Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin');

    // Sliders
    Route::get('/sliders', 'SliderController@listSlider'); // List Sliders
    Route::post('/sliders/new', 'SliderController@createSlider'); // New Slider
    Route::get('/sliders/edit/{id}', ['as' => '/sliders/edit/', 'uses' => 'SliderController@editSlider']); // Edit Slider

    // Slides
    Route::post('/slides/create/', 'SlideController@createSlide'); // Create Slide
    Route::post('/slides/update', 'SlideController@updateSlide'); // Update Slide
    Route::post('/slides/delete/', 'SlideController@deleteSlide'); // Delete Slide
});
```

If I try to go to /login it works well, loads all the style and js files (which are on the same folder as /admin files), it actually works 100% well.

It should redirect from /admin to /login if the user is not authenticated, but again this /admin route have no action, not even a 404 error, it just tries to load again the main page, which leads to css and js erros because of wrong path for these assets.

This only happens on Linux so I have no clue what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be having conflicts with your 'admin' ***route*** and your 'admin' ***public directory***, try changing either one of those.

Comment: You're right! I fixed a similar issue before, but the behavior was different, should've known it.